# Only 'Title' menu while creating new page. Install Wagtail

Tags: python, django, installation, django-settings, wagtail

I've tryed CMS Wagtail. Installed from  [docs](http://wagtail.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0b2/getting_started/installation.html)
It was installed without errors, everything was fine (I decided to leave sqlite3 DB). After entering to admin panel CMS, I
 can create only page with a title. E.g. While creating a new page, i have only 'Title' menu. On a screenshots and video i see that
 there also should be menus STRAPLINE, BACKGROUND IMAGE etc. My case: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loQJu.png)
Please help to switch these functions on and to start using it full.

I've just started learning Python and Django, and if it necessary to add smth to the sourcecode (for solving my problem) please show me how to do it or send me the links how other do it,or advise me what i should read in the documentation for fast adding necessary to the code.

best,
Roman

Comment: wagtail isn't usable out of the box. You have to write code before adding any content.

Comment: Honestly this was a big disappointment to me. The product looks very powerful and has a ton of integrations thanks to the Django community but out of the box it's nothing much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before creating pages in Wagtail, you're expected to define some page models - these determine which input fields appear on the edit form. See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v0.8.7/core_components/pages/creating_pages.html